# How to square a rising share price with the company diluting the value of its existing shares

Tags: shares, corporate-acquisition

Company A's share price in the market continues to rise while at the same time, the company keeps announcing that they are issuing new shares for multiple M&A transactions.
How is this possible ? Isn't it true that new shares will generally dilute the existing share value? Or is it because the market expects that the M&As will soon/immediately increase the total market cap ? Are there other explanations for this phenomenon ?

Comment: This is the same scenario discussed in [How does a public company issue new shares without diluting the value held by existing shareholders?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/how-does-a-public-company-issue-new-shares-without-diluting-the-value-held-by-ex) except that the increase in assets comes from the acquisition, not cash.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it because the market expects that the M&As will soon/immediately increase the total market cap ?

Yes. The total number of shares outstanding has increased, making each share a smaller fraction of the company, but the company itself has *grown* as a result of the transaction, so it is entirely possible for the shares to maintain their value.

If company A acquires company B and compensates B's shareholders with ownership of x% of the combined company (by issuing new A shares), the existing shareholders of A now own (100 - x)% instead of 100%. So they have lost x% of the existing company A, but they have *gained* (100 - x)% of B which wasn't part of the company's value previously. If the price of the acquisition is fair, it's a wash.

The negative effect of dilution occurs when the company "over-issues" its shares, obtaining too little in return or squandering what it does obtain (cash or acquired company).